# Ng-click restrained within ion-slide

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic framework.

I have multiple slide boxes being generated by ng-repeat. For each slide box I wanted to have a section that will appear underneath when the button in the ion-slide is clicked. The code below explains what am I trying to do and what does and does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false">

    <ion-slide>
        TEST111111111111
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
        TEST222222222222
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
        TEST333333333333

        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="test = !test">
        Test
        </button>

        Works > True or False? > {{test}}
    </ion-slide>

</ion-slide-box>

Does not work > True or False? > {{test}}
```

Comment: Could you give us some more details ? Do you have any code in your controller ? It looks like a scope problem with `test` only being populated in a child scope (ng repeat creates a child scope each time), but it's hard to tell if you don't provide us more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a variable with a `.` (dot).  See [Understanding Scopes in AngularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false">

    <ion-slide>
        TEST111111111111
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
        TEST222222222222
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
        TEST333333333333

        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="someObject.test = !someObject.test">
        Test
        </button>

        Works > True or False? > {{someObject.test}}
    </ion-slide>

</ion-slide-box>

Does not work > True or False? > {{someObject.test}}
```

And make sure that in your controller you also initialize a value for `someObject`

```
$scope.someObject = {
    test: false
};
```